# How many service we can Inject in the root injector in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-services

When I create a service , set `providerIn:"root"` for it , I know this service will be singleton, as below :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class UserService {
}
```

but I want to know:

Is there any limitation ,How many service we can Inject the root injector of angular ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Is this out of curiosity (which is fine!) or do you have a usecase behind this question ? If you do have a specific usecase, please provide more information so we can give you a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Angular's [documentation on dependency injection](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection) does not mention any limitations. So does the [documentation on singletons](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services).

So as far as the official documentation goes, you can provide and inject as many singletons as you like in the application's root.